# How to output codeigniter selects_sum in the view without foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

How can I output the result of `select_sum` from controller to the view without using foreach. I don't want to use foreach because my function returns only 1 number.

The logic is I have a column in DB with numeric values called 'time', I want to sum all of them together, and output the result next to /10000 in my view.

I believe I need to use `row()` but I am not sure how.

Controller:

```
$this->load->library(array('form_validation', 'session'));
    $this->db->select_sum('time');
    $data['num'] = $this->db->get('posts');

    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    $data['query'] = $this->db->get('posts');
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
    $this->load->view('home_page', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

View:

```
<?php foreach ($num->result() as $row): ?>
        <?php if (empty($row->time)): echo "0"?>
        <?php else: echo $row->time ?>
        <?php endif ?>/10000</p>
        <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `row()` with the variable.

```
$sql = $this->db->select_sum('time');
$sql = $this->db->get('posts');
$data['num'] = $sql->row();
```

And you can call in your view

```
$num->time;
```

hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that worked. Just a syntax question, can I unite $sql = $this->db->select_sum('time');
$sql = $this->db->get('posts'); into one variable or array or object so that I can use it in my controller again without duplicating these lines. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Correct, I suppose I can use $sql in my controller for other instances.